# Error Building project with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I updated Android Studio and then I cannot build an app

This is my message from Gradle

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.2.0.
 Required by:
     BT_QuinielaCatamarca:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0
     BT_QuinielaCatamarca:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.2.0
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.2.0.
     > Could not parse POM D:\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-identity\10.2.0\play-services-identity-10.2.0.pom
        > Content is not allowed in prolog.
 > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.2.0.
 Required by:
     BT_QuinielaCatamarca:app:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0
  > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.2.0.
     > Could not parse POM D:\Android\Sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-nearby\10.2.0\play-services-nearby-10.2.0.pom
        > Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

And this is my build.gradle file
The app use jsoup library to parse

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "info.blacktrail.quinielacatamarca"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 13
    versionName "3.47"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {

    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()

}
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.8.1.jar')

compile files('libs/htmlcleaner-2.16.jar')
}
```

I tried several things like changing the BuildTools or others SDK versions

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the end of your gradle (level app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

You also have to add google-services to your class-path at project level gradle :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

And ensure that you have installed `Google repository` under `Extra` in you r SDK.

Comment: Both items was already added and Google repository was already installed too.

Comment: did you tried to put this line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
` at the end of the file instead of being in the second line